# Application is crashing due to ClassCastException in Android studio

Tags: java, android

```
public class DialogUtil extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private EditText mName;
private DialogUtilListener listener;

private String mTitle = "Title";
private String mNegative = "Negative";
private String mPositive = "Positive";

public void setDialog(String Name, String pos, String neg){
    mTitle = Name;
    mNegative = neg;
    mPositive = pos;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Resource.getAppContext());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
    mName = view.findViewById(R.id.editName_ID);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle(mTitle)
            .setNegativeButton(mNegative, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Log.d("Dialog", "Cancelled..!");
                }})
            .setPositiveButton(mPositive, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String Name = mName.getText().toString();;
                    listener.applyText(Name);
                    Log.d("Dialog", "File Name saved");
                }});
    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        listener = (DialogUtilListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
         "must implement DialogUtilListener");
    }
}

public interface DialogUtilListener{
    void applyText(String Name);
}
```

I have written the above code for the dialog to get the name form the user to store a file. The code is getting crashed always in onAttach method and throwing class cast exception.

Following is the code I am using in my activity class.

```
private void openDialog(){
     DialogUtil mDialog = new DialogUtil();
     mDialog.setDialog("Map Name", "Save", "Cancel");
     mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Map Dialog");
}

private DialogUtil.DialogUtilListener mDialogListener = new DialogUtil.DialogUtilListener() {
    @Override
    public void applyText(String Name) {
        Log.d("DialogText", "Name: " + Name);
    }
};
```

How can I get rid of this error? Is there anyway I can use the same code with only change in the line causing the error? 
Thanks in advance.

I am also attaching the image of the exception appeared on the log cat for your reference.[Error as appeared on log cat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiFBx.png)

Comment: Stacktrace has the information you need, the object you pass to onAttach must be a class that implements DialogUtilListener.

Comment: why this: listener = (DialogUtilListener) context;   and not this: listener = new DialogUtilListener(){ @Override
            public applyText(String Name) {
            } };     and less I forgot the class that make use of the interface must implement DialogUtilListener

Comment: Yes, I am implementing the DialogUtilListener in the activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity, get rid of this:

> ```
> private DialogUtil.DialogUtilListener mDialogListener = new DialogUtil.DialogUtilListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void applyText(String Name) {
>         Log.d("DialogText", "Name: " + Name);
>     }
> };
> ```

Instead, declare that your activity implements the listener:

```
public class MyActivity implements DialogUtil.DialogUtilListener
```

And then put the interface method directly in your activity:

```
@Override
public void applyText(String Name) {
    Log.d("DialogText", "Name: " + Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work for me. But why was my previous code not working? Since I am following same coding pattern it will be helpful if you can tell me if there is a way I can correct it using the old format.

Comment: Your fragment's `onAttach()` method is called whenever your fragment is attached to an activity (it is called automatically by the android framework). Because of the way your `onAttach()` method is written, your Activity must implement the listener interface. This is actually the best way to do it; it will let your fragment work even after being destroyed and recreated by the system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me

Answer (score 1):

Your host activity must implement DialogUtil.DialogUtilListener

Answer (score -1):

You should do instaceof check before actually doing cast, something like below.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
     super.onAttach(context);
     try {
         if (context instanceof DialogUtilListener){
             listener = (DialogUtilListener) context;
         }
     } catch (ClassCastException e) {
         throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
          "must implement DialogUtilListener");
     }
}
```

That way you will get idea on which object you are getting and take necessary action.